# How make the textmeshpro text to be in front of rawimage or just image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i don't want to make the image transparent but to make the text to be on the image.
now the black image is blocking the text.

The canvas is set to screen space overlay.

[image: ui text is blocked by the rawimage/image]

Comment: Just to make sure you checked it, you did change the color of the text, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming the text colour is different from the image colour as @alfix suggested) if changing the Z position of the canvas elements doesn't change their render order, reordering them in the hierarchy should. Objects lower in the hierarchy should render on top of items prior to them in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

So all the normal approaches wont solve this - you need to go to the textMeshPro object and got to Extra Settings and increase the 'Order In Layer' there.

[image]